# How to dynamically apply variables to the values of a dictionary using Python and/or RobotFramework

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

Say I have a list of dictionaries:

```
URL_LIST = [
    {'google': 'http://www.google.com/join'},
    {'yahoo':  'http://www.yahoo.com/{0}/join'},
    {'msn':    'http://www.msn.com/{0}/join'}
]
```

Now, I want to pass this dictionary to a python function, along with two other variables, so that the two variables replaces the `{0}`s in the `'yahoo'` and `'msn'` variables:

```
def apply_arguments (url_list, yahoo_subpage, msn_subpage):
    #Do stuff
    return url_list
```

So if the `yahoo_suboage = 'aaa'` and `msn_subpage = 'bbb'`, I want the final result to be like this:

```
URL_LIST = [
    {'google': 'http://www.google.com/join'},
    {'yahoo':  'http://www.yahoo.com/aaa/join'},
    {'msn':    'http://www.msn.com/bbb/join'}
]
```

I want to do it using either python or RobotFramework. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `URL_LIST` is unnecessarily nested, so I use a `list` in this answer.

```
lst = [
    'http://www.google.com/join',
    'http://www.yahoo.com/{0}/join',
    'http://www.msn.com/{0}/join',
]

dct = {
    'yahoo': 'aaa',
    'msn': 'bbb',
}

def make_changes(lst, dct):

    for i, url in enumerate(lst):
        k = url.split('.')[1]
        
        try:
            lst[i] = url.replace('{0}', dct[k])
        except:
            pass
            
    return lst
     

print(make_changes(lst, dct))
```

Output:

```
['http://www.google.com/join', 'http://www.yahoo.com/aaa/join', 'http://www.msn.com/bbb/join']
```